# putting a formula into a for loop

Tags: java, loops, recursion, factorial

I'm trying to put this formula into a loop

[The function to put inside the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5wJ1.png)

I've used if statements to give me a specific result if the input is zero, but if the input is one or higher, the for loop should run.

I was given a question regards recursion and supposed to execute it 3 different ways one of them using a loop that I've already made and runs but gives unexpected results.

```
public class Assignment5Recursion {
public static int puzzleLoop(int n) {
    int v=0;
    if(n>=1) {
        for(int i=1; i<=n+1; i++) {
            v = (2*i-1);
        }
        return ((2*n+1)+2*v);
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }}}
```

if n is 1, the result should be 5, if n is 2, the result should be 13, if n is 3, the result should be 25, if n is 7, the result should be 113, but for some reason, I'm getting different outputs, so I'm assuming that I've set the loop wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes.

1)The loop will run from `i=1` to `i=n+1` whereas you only require it to run till `i=n`.

So the for loop exit condition should either be `i<n+1` or `i<=n`

2)The variable v is going to be replaced every run of the loop as it is getting assigned a new value every time.

So the value for v will always be `v=2*(n+1)-1` according to your code.

You need to make this  `v += (2*i-1)` so that the new value of v gets added to the old value to get sigma(sum).

Replacing your for loop as below will solve your problem.

```
for(int i=1; i<n+1; i++) {
        v += (2*i-1);
}
```

or

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        v = v+(2*i-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made two mistake, instead of adding to v you are updating on every iteration, so total values doesn't get summed up. And since you are using `<=` you don't need to iterate upto `n+1`. So here is a revised `puzzleLoop` method for you

```java
public static int puzzleLoop(int n) {
    int v = 0;

    if (n >= 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            v += (2 * i - 1);
        }

        return ((2 * n + 1) + 2 * v);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

You also don't need the else part statement since if it is not in the `if` block you can always safely return 1.

Answer (score 0):

Σ(2*i-1), sum should be carried over the loop

change the statement in loop to  v = v+(2*i-1) and condition to i<=n